# Where does the command "ssh-keygen -A" generate host keys?

Tags: ssh, hosts, sshd, ssh-keygen

I tried to start sshd and saw an error message as follow.

```
# sshd: no hostkeys available --exiting
```

And did some search and found I need to run the command "ssh-keygen -A" to generate default host keys.
And I was successfully started sshd after running "ssh-keygen -A" command.
But I still don't know what keys are generated and where those are stored when I run "ssh-keygen -A".

Comment: So did you run `sudo service ssh --full-restart` after you ran `sudo ssh-keygen -A`?

Comment: I just did /sbin/sshd -D -f /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Comment: Did you run `sudo service ssh --full-restart`?

Comment: No, I didn't run sudo service ssh --full-restart

Comment: So can you run it?  So can you restart the service is order for the update configuration to take effect?

Comment: sshd is running with the command I used. But my question is the effect of "ssh-keygen -A". What does this command do?

Comment: `ssh-keygen -A` does not start sshd.  `ssh-keygen` is a different application.

Comment: I know. That is not my question. Please see my question.

Comment: I did. Is your question what ssh-keygen -A does or how to solve your error?

Answer (score 1):

`ssh-keygen -A` by default generates in `/etc/ssh` on Debian and some other systems.  The location may differ on other systems where it is compiled differently.

Usually the files end up being these:

- `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key`
- `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub`
- `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key`
- `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub`
- `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key`
- `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub`

The files ending in `.pub` are the public keys and the ones without that ending are the corresponding private keys.  On older systems, DSA keys may also be generated, but they are insecure (both in that they are using 1024-bit primes and that they use SHA-1), and should not be used.